# if something described in the question turned out to be a bug and was fixed later

Tags: discussion

I am browsing through some of my old questions, some of which have *already been resolved*.

After I asked such a question and didn't get an answer for a long time, I reported the case described in the question to GNU.
They explained that it was a bug and, ultimately, they fixed it.

Then I added the bug ID (i.e., `bug#NNNNN`) at the end of the descriptive text for that question, intending to express that it has been *solved*.
However, on the Stack Exchange side, the question still remains in *unanswered* state.

I plan to close the question, yet cannot find a suitable reason.
Should we add a new closing reason to handle a similar situation, or is there any better choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be fair to create an answer which explains that it was a bug, indicates what the correct behavior was supposed to be, what date it was fixed, and in which version of emacs the fix was deployed.. and then accept that answer.